Computer randomly loses internet connection
My computer (Windows 10 build 19045) sometimes loses internet connection. It's only happened while I'm using the browser (Chrome Version 128.0.6613.138), but other than that it's seemingly random. If I plug the ethernet cable into another computer everything works fine, so I assume it's not my router/modem/ISP that's the issue.
When this happens, Windows claims that it's still connected to the internet, but I can't access anything. The Windows network troubleshooter states that the DNS isn't responding, but that seems weird given that the DNS responds when I use another computer. They only way I've found of reconnecting is to restart my computer.

Does it come back automatically?   How long can you use it before you lose connection?  It could be hardware, cable, router, software

It hasn't come back automatically so far. Sometimes it happens once a week, sometimes once a day. I'm guessing it is triggered by an action I'm doing, I just can't figure out what.

desktop? Did you try another port? I had an isp-supplied router that would shut down ports to specific computers. Possibly flood protection or a bug. Never narrowed it down but I thought it was related to apple's Bonjour (mDNS I think)
